# Reset firmware password Macbook pro 13"

Tags: macbook

Is there any way i can reset my firmware password on my Mac-book pro 13" (Late 2011 model) without having to purchase new RAM?

Thanks

Comment: Ram wouldn't have anything to do with anything - it by nature stops storing anything if power isn't applied to it.

Comment: Is there anything i can do?